# how to use fabrication gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Ok, please bear with me as I've never tested in Rails (literally).

I was trying to use Faker gem to fill in some data, but was having trouble since the association is:

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :photos
end


class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :photo, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :photo, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
    belongs_to :gallery
end
```

So, someone told me to use `Fabrication` gem. Like I said, never have done any testing at all ... so not really sure how to implement this gem so I can create some dummy info.

This is what I've done so far:

**spec/fabricators/gallery_fabricator.rb**

```
Fabricator(:gallery) do
 title { Faker::Book.title }
end
```

**spec/fabricators/photo_fabricator.rb**

```
Fabricator(:photo) do
 title { Faker::Book.title }
 description { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
end
```

And this is what I have in **seeds.rb**

```
Fabricate :gallery do
 title { Faker::Book.title }
end

Fabricate :photo do
 title { Faker::Superhero.name }
 description { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
 photo { Faker::Placeholdit.image }
end
```

It sorta works, as it creates a single title for Gallery album every time I run `rake db:seed` but nothing for photos ...

Advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your seeds file, just use:

```
Fabricate :gallery
Fabricate :photo
```

If you want to add photos in your gallery fabricator (let's say 5 photos):

```
Fabricator(:gallery) do
    title { Faker::Book.title }
    photos(count: 5)
end
```

Fabricator understands Rails associations, so it will use the photo fabricator to create these photos.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey thanks. Accepted your answer because it works. A follow-up question if you don't mind? I tried this: `photos(count: 5) { Faker::Placeholderit.image}` ... and it gives me errors like this: `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Photo(#70257211428680) expected, got String(#70257158998840)` ... any way to be able to use Faker::Placeholderit.image? No worries if you don't want to answer it ... I'll post it as a separate question ...

Comment: Use the `Faker::Placeholderit.image` in your photo fabricator as you already did. The block you added after `photos(count: 5)` expects a Photo object, not a string (returned by faker), this is why you get an error.

Comment: hey thanks ... based on what you said, got it working. upvoted your ans to give extra points! =)